# Loading a FileDescriptorSet from proto files without generating intermediate files

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm aware that `protoc` provides a way to generate proto file descriptors from `.proto` files with the help of `--descriptor_set_out` option. I would like to do this on the fly without generating any intermediate files, effectively loading the descriptor directly into memory as a `google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2.FileDescriptorSet`.

Is there such an option in `protoc` or python's `google.protobuf` package?